# SQL - STDEVP of multiple groups

Tags: sql, ssms

I currently have a query to get me the usage of an item by week:

```
SELECT Item, SUM(Quantity * PackQty) AS Usage
FROM [Database].[dbo].Transactions
WHERE Transactions.Type in ('I') AND Date > DATEADD(year, -1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY Item, Datepart(week, MyDate)
ORDER BY Item
```

It's output is like so:

```
**Item**   **Usage**
9999          10
9999          2
9999          1
9999          1
9999          1
9999          2
00125         5
00135         9
00135         10
00135         10
00159         2
00159         2
00159         6
00159         2
00159         4
00159         4
00159         4
00159         4
.....        ...
```

I am wanting to get the STDEVP for each item where the population is the usages.
For example, I am wanting:

```
**Item**       **STDEVP**
9999             3.236
00125            0
00135            0.471  
00159            1.323
.....            .....
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT Item, SUM(Quantity * PackQty), STDEVP(Quantity * PackQty) AS Usage
FROM [Database].[dbo].Transactions
WHERE Transactions.Type in ('I') AND Date > DATEADD(year, -1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY Item
ORDER BY Item;
```

EDIT:

If you need it for the original query, use a subquery:

```
SELECT Item, STDEVP(qp) AS Usage
FROM (SELECT Item, Datepart(week, MyDate) as myweek, SUM(Quantity * PackQty) as qp
      FROM [Database].[dbo].Transactions
      WHERE Transactions.Type in ('I') AND Date > DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
      GROUP BY Item, Datepart(week, MyDate)
     ) iw
GROUP BY Item
ORDER BY Item;
```

Comment: The original query is putting the usages into weekly usages. I need to get the STDEVP where the population is the weekly usages. What you provided is using the original data which is per transaction. This results in the Standard Dev. to be much lower than before. This is why Datepart(week, MyDate) was added. Hopes that makes sense.